# Can't get back the array from completion handler

Tags: ios, closures, completionhandler

I am reading data from FireStore and storing it in my array. The data I am getting is inside closure, so I had to use Completion Handler to pass it outside the function. But I am not able to get the value of my array when I am calling my completion handler function. All its printing is [Project.CellComponents]. I know there must be some silly mistakes and I am sorry for that as I am just a starter.

OwnerHomeViewController:

```
class OwnerHomeViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    var listingDetailArray:[CellComponents] = []
    var docRef:DocumentReference!

    var typeOfListing:String = ""
    var charges:Int = 0
    var rating:Float = 0.0
    var nameOfListing:String = ""
    var cityName:String = ""
    var details:String = ""
    var currency:String = ""
    var days:String = ""

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCell.SeparatorStyle.none

        getDataFromDB { (array) in
            print(array) ////Result in console '[Project.CellComponents]'
            listingDetailArray = array
        }
    }

    func getDataFromDB(completionHandler: @escaping(_ array: [CellComponents]) -> ()) {
        var tempArray:[CellComponents] = []

        docRef = Firestore.firestore().document("/Property/ktgEh96NXXTShCOBwj8QpEM79PB3/Hotel/2")
        docRef.getDocument { (docSnapshot, error) in
            if error != nil {
                return
            }
            else {

                guard let docSnapshot = docSnapshot, docSnapshot.exists else { print("Error found");return }
                let myData = docSnapshot.data()
                print(myData?["Type"] as? String ?? "")
                self.typeOfListing = myData?["Type"] as? String ?? "Not Found"
                self.charges = Int(myData?["Charges"] as? String ?? "Not Found") ?? 0
                self.nameOfListing = myData?["Title"] as? String ?? "Not Found"
                self.currency = myData?["Currency"] as? String ?? "Not Found"
                self.days = myData?["Days"] as? String ?? "Not Found"
                self.details = myData?["Description"] as? String ?? "Not Found"

                let data2 = CellComponents(image: UIImage(named: "b")!, typeOfListing: self.typeOfListing , charges: self.charges, rating: 4.1, nameOfListing: self.nameOfListing , cityName: "Rawalpindi", detail: self.details, currency: self.currency, days: self.days)

                tempArray.append(data2)
                completionHandler(_:tempArray)
            }
        }
    }
}

extension OwnerHomeViewController:UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return listingDetailArray.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let listingData = listingDetailArray[indexPath.row]
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "OwnerHomeCell") as! OwnerHomeTableViewCell
        cell.setListingData(array: listingData)
        cell.details.isEditable = false
        return cell
    }
}
```

And that my CellComponent class

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class CellComponents {

    var image: UIImage
    var typeOfListing:String
    var charges:Int
    var rating:Float
    var nameOfListing: String
    var cityName : String
    var detail : String
    var currency:String
    var days:String


    init (image:UIImage, typeOfListing:String, charges:Int, rating:Float, nameOfListing:String, cityName:String, detail:String, currency: String, days:String)
    {
        self.image = image
        self.typeOfListing = typeOfListing
        self.charges = charges
        self.rating = rating
        self.nameOfListing = nameOfListing
        self.cityName = cityName
        self.detail = detail
        self.currency = currency
        self.days = days

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There're some early return in your code. You can mark and debug it.

Comment: Please be more precise with your answer!

Comment: if error != nil {
                return
            } 
and guard let else { return }
If error happen here, it wont call completionHandler

Comment: No. I have checked that part. There is no error there.